# changing intercept logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic

I did logistic regression and got an intercept of `-14` and a `beta_1` of `0.17`.

My equation is: `-14 + 0.17*x = y`

How can I calculate the change of probability if `x` increases by `0.1`, assuming a original probability of `20%`?

Can I change `beta_0` to `log(0.2/0.8)` and then add `0.1*0.17`?

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track. You need to do the calculation you suggested, then convert back to the probability scale and subtract 0.2 (the baseline probability).

```r
plogis(qlogis(0.2) + 0.17*0.1) - 0.2
## [1] 0.002733877
```

`qlogis()` is the logit (log-odds) transformation (i.e. `log(0.2/0.8) = qlogis(0.2)`); `plogis()` is the logistic, or inverse-logit transformation

If the starting probability were closer to 0.5 you could use the rule of thumb that the inverse-logit/logistic curve is approximately linear with slope beta/4 in the range (0.3, 0.7); in this case 0.17/4*0.1 gives 0.00425, which is the right order of magnitude but off by about 50% ... (for a starting probability of 0.3 it's only off by 30%)